# Get a specific id in a modal

Tags: swift, swiftui, modal-dialog, parent-child

I'm still learning on the job and my question may seem stupid.

I've got a list of movies and on the tap I want to show card of the selected movie.

So I've got my ResultsView

```
    var results:[DiscoverResult]
    @State private var resultsCount:Int = 0
    @State private var isPresented:Bool = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var genres:Genres
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            ForEach (results){ result in
                Button(action: {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                    
                }, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        ZStack {
                            KFImage(URL (string: baseUrlForThumb + result.posterPath)).resizable().scaledToFill()
                                .frame( height: 150)
                                .mask(Rectangle().frame( height: 150))
                            
                            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)        // Making rectangle transparent
                                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .clear, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                        }.frame( height: 150)
                        // Titre du film
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(result.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            
                            // Genres du film
                            Text(genres.generateGenresList(genreIDS: result.genreIDS)).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.white).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }     .padding()
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                  
                    
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                    MovieView(isPresented: $isPresented, movieId: result.id)
                })
                .navigationTitle(result.title)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my MovieView

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
  var movieId:Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(movieId))
                .padding()
     
            Button("Fermer") {
                isPresented = false
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

But the movie card still the same even list element selected.

I think that the 'result.id' is overwrite at every loop but i don't know how to fix it.

Sorry for my english mistakes.

thank for your purpose.

Comment: try a `didSet` on `movieId` variable to see if it s getting set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `isPresented` for `.sheet` you can use `.sheet(item:, content:)` and pass the whole `result` object

```
.sheet(item: $selecteditem( { result in
    MovieView(item: result)
}
```

To make this work you need a new property (you can remove isPresented)

```
@State private var selectedItem: DiscoverResult?
```

and you need update your `MovieView` struct

```
struct MovieView: View {
    let result: DiscoverResult
    var body: some View {
        //...
    }
}
```

or pass only the movie id to your MovieView if you prefer that.

Comment: Thanks a lot 2 days stuck on this problem :)